# how to make a div movable up and down and also swap id variables using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, moveabletype

**is it possible to make a div movable up and down and also change value of the ID when toggled up and down?**

*EX*:

```
<div id="main_window">
     <div id="window_1"> //this window moves down and also 
         <input id="var_1"> //gets the value of "3" from the div below
     </div>
     <div id="window_3"> //this window moves up and also
         <select id="var_3"></select> //gets the value of "1" from the div above
     </div>
     <div id="window_6">
         <textarea id="var_6"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div id="window_8">
         <input id="var_7">

     </div>
</div>
```

**the div when pushed up should acquire the highest id / name value but not switch content only the id variable.**

**the move event can be done by click or drag as long as the goal is accomplished**

Comment: You are moving div by drag and drop or by click of any event?

Comment: drop or click as long as the objective can be done

Comment: You didn't write any javascript... You should show an attempt at coming to the solution, yourself... yes, it's possible...

Comment: that is why i'm asking if it's possible because i haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easy movable divs using jQuery I would suggest using [jQueryUI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

You can reassign the id/name values in a event handler like `update` [[docs]](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update)

Comment: Yes, you will need to call `refresh` [\[docs\]](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) though

Comment: tried this it does support dynamic elements, but the problem now is ho to update id / name variables

Comment: like I said, you should use the events like `update` as documented

Comment: already have the answer $('#selectable .count').prop('value', function(i) { return ++i; });